# Как сделать лупы как из соника

Tags: c#, unity3d

я хочу сделать луп де лупы как из соника я искал ничего не нашел может кто нибудь помочь?[image: лупы]

Comment: не уверен, но наверно это делается через `NavMesh`. Вообще очень полезная и юзабельная штука

Comment: но как сделать в 2d тоже через NavMesh?

Comment: нет навмеша для 2д. а как сделать в 2д такое я не знаю. извиняй

Comment: ок у меня есть уже идея